# IE adding content-type multipart/form-data to GET requests

Tags: internet-explorer, amazon-s3, http-headers

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='submit' name='foo' />
</form>
```

When that form is submitted, I have some PHP that renders an image:

`<img src="http://s3-external-1.amazonaws/bucket/example.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=foo&Signature=bar&expires=111111" />`

The problem is that Internet Explorer 11 (and other versions I believe) are sending a `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dfcd3b0f0a` on that GET request.

When AWS receives the request, they say the signature doesn't match (rightly so).

Few weird quirks:

- If I load the page with HTTPS, the content type is not set to any value (so it works)
- This doesn't happen in any other browsers
- If I have the dev tools open in IE, the content type is not set to any value (so it works)
- If I remove `multipart/form-data` the content type is not set to any value (so it works)

I have tried issuing a cURL request with/without the `content-type`. It fails with, and succeeds without.

Why would IE be adding a `content-type` to all GETs on the resulting page after a form submit?

update: It doesn't appear to happen with all forms - but when we submit from a certain part of our application, this happens. Near as I can find, the form on the submitting page is identical, but the form data is put through a different server-side function before the image is rendered. Can't see how this affects IE adding a content-type however.