# How to remove Content-Type from multipart/form-data Body Request?

Tags: javascript, angular, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload array of files as multipart/form data.
I use ngx-file-upload v6.0.1

Here is slightly changed method from the library example. I am copying it to show that file is of type File.

```
public onFileAdded (files: UploadFile[]) {
for (const droppedFile of files) {
  if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
    const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
    fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
      this.certificates$.next({
        type: ACTIONS.ADD,
        value: new Certificate(file, this.getSizeString(file.size), droppedFile.relativePath)
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here is onSubmit method:

```
public submitCertificates(certificates: Certificate[]): Observable<Certificate[]> {
const url = this.completionCertificatesUrl;
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});

const formData = new FormData();
certificates.forEach(certificate => {
  formData.append('files', certificate.file, certificate.relativePath);
})

return this.http.post<any>(url, formData, {headers}).pipe(
  map(data => data)
);
```

Post request that is sent has following data:
[request payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzpCB.png)

The problem is that backend (Spring framework which I have no access to and no understanding) throws 500 and does not accept this payload.
I was told that correct payload should look like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=79ab782d574b45598e6e50d722985144

--79ab782d574b45598e6e50d722985144
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="file-1.json"

content of file-1 file
--79ab782d574b45598e6e50d722985144
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="fil2-2.zip"

content of file-2 file
--79ab782d574b45598e6e50d722985144--
```

My questions is how can I remove "Content-Type" key from my payload?

I did try a lot of combinations of append(), delete() to no result.
Also, my concern is if the file is really attached to this request. Can I check it anyhow?

I wonder if I am missing the content of the file altogether, because in the example I was provided there is a line "content of file-1" and maybe this is a shortcut for a much longer string that would represent the file content.
Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

> My questions is how can I remove "Content-Type" key from my payload?

Look at where you set it:

Delete this line:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});
```

Delete `headers` from this line.

```
return this.http.post<any>(url, formData, {headers}).pipe(
```

Comment: Hi @Quentin, unfortunately , this does not solve the problem.
Headers here set headers in the Headers section of the request.
I need to erase "Content-Type="application/json" " from the payload part of the request.
Here is a similar issue described in similar words, but imo the problem is not same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584155/ie-adding-content-type-multipart-form-data-to-get-requests

Comment: @Marcin – That doesn't make sense. The parts **must** have a `Content-Type` header unless they are plain text. Otherwise it violates [the spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html). There's no way to stop the browser adding them AFAIK. (Explicitly setting  `HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})` should cause a problem because the `boundary` parameter is missing, so removing that should fix problems, but removing the Content-Type from the individual parts should only create problems, even if it were possible)

Comment: How you made this work?